# why does underscore find method unset a previously set variable?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, undefined

In the following code fragment - why does the progression variable get set to "undefined" after the second call to _.find?

```
var progression = _.find(window.programCycle.progressions[progressionTabIndex], 
  function (item) {
    console.log('item.id = ',parseInt(item.id));
    console.log('wId = ',parseInt(wId));
    console.log(parseInt(item.id) == parseInt(wId));
    return parseInt(item.id) == parseInt(wId);
  });
console.log(progression); // progression is seen here as expected
var meal = _.find(window.programCycle.meals, 
  function (item) {
    return item.meal == exc.meal;
  });
progression.meal = meal.id; // at this line progression has already been set to "undefined", the value from just before the "var meal" line has been lost.
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How do you know that `progression` is undefined at that point?

Comment: Can you make a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? This sounds like your problem is outside of the provided snippet.

Comment: @Thomas  because I step through the code in the developer tools in chrome and inspected the variable - I also hit a crash there that says "cannot set variable meal of undefined"

Comment: Sorry - the code is in a loop and when I stepped over it again I added more console.log massages which let me see the progression  variable get set to undefined where it normally gets set on the find() call.  Why the inspector was reporting a value there before and then crashing on the set progression.meal line I don't know but it seems that it was not he second call to _.find doing the damage.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `_.clone` to make new object when using `_.find`

```
var progression = _.clone(_.find(window.programCycle.progressions[progressionTabIndex], 
  function (item) {
    console.log('item.id = ',parseInt(item.id));
    console.log('wId = ',parseInt(wId));
    console.log(parseInt(item.id) == parseInt(wId));
    return parseInt(item.id) == parseInt(wId);
  }), true);
console.log(progression); // progression is seen here as expected
var meal = _.clone(_.find(window.programCycle.meals, 
  function (item) {
    return item.meal == exc.meal;
  }), true);
progression.meal = meal.id;
```

Because `find` in lodash is not create new object, it just make a reference

```js
var a = [
  {name: 'aaa', sport: 'football'},
  {name: 'bbb', sport: 'golf'}
];
var b = _.find(a, function(item) {
  return item.name === 'aaa';
});
b.sport = 'cooking';
console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.5/lodash.min.js">
```

Or see the codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bMdeWw